# Django many to many serializers circular dependency work around?

Tags: python, django, circular-dependency

I have two models, publications and articles, that are connected to each other by a ManyToManyField. I want to be able to return what publications are connected to a certain article, and what articles are connected to a certain publication within my views. Models shown below

```
class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publications = models.ManyToManyField('Publication')

class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

I want to reference articles to publication and publications to articles in both model serializers.

```
class PublicationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    title = serializers.CharField()
    articles = ???
    class Meta:
        model = Publication
        fields = ['title', 'articles']

class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    headline = serializers.CharField()
    publications = PublicationSerializer(many=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['headline', 'publications']
```

I have been looking up various solutions, many refer to using Relational Fields, such as StringRelatedField, and saw a different solution using SerializerMethodField(), but there doesn't appear to be much documentation on them. Any examples or solutions to this issue?

Comment: It makes no sense to do that, since your output can then result in infinite recursion. The response would ontain article with publications with articles with publications,  ...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem so what would be the appropriate thing to do if I wanted to see all Articles that connect to a certain publication?

Comment: make another serializer for `Article` that only "nests" one level deep.

Comment: @PhilCho Willem is right. You are not using related_names='' in many to many field.
When you have many to many or any kind of relation you use `publications = models.ManyToManyField('Publication',related_names = "articles")`. 
So when you have an object of Publication pub you can do `pub.articles` for reverse relation.